# Extract|Grep|Substring character vector in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, vector

String that start with ^passport only those entry need to be captured

example :

```
entry = c("passport AR4133553 expires 11 mar 2019","passport 472420180","passport 563220533 (korea, north)",
          "passport iraq","passport m 788439","following data derived from an eritrean passport issued",
          "passport and national")
```

desired output : Data has to capture only the passport and country name

```
**passport**  **passport_country**  
"AR4133553"   NA   
"472420180"   NA   
"563220533"   "korea, north"  
NA            "iraq"  
"788439"      NA  
NA            NA  
NA            NA
```

Comment: https://informatique-mia.inra.fr/r4ciam/node/148

Comment: Not able to get the required output. I know the regex pattern. 
Some how not able to generate desired output.

Please help me with pseudo code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try and what output did you get ? Please, have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share a minimal reproducible piece of code so we can help you effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
#sample data
entry = c("passport AR4133553 expires 11 mar 2019",
          "passport 472420180",
          "passport 563220533 (korea, north)",
          "passport iraq",
          "passport m 788439",
          "following data derived from an eritrean passport issued",
          "passport and national") 

#fetch passport number from sample data (i.e. second string having numbers which is immediately after 'passport')
passport_no <- gsub("^passport\\s((([a-zA-Z]*\\d)|(\\d[a-zA-Z]*))\\S*).*", "\\1", entry, perl=T)
ind <- grep("^passport\\s((([a-zA-Z]*\\d)|(\\d[a-zA-Z]*))\\S*).*", entry, value=F)
passport_no[-ind] <- NA

#fetch passport country from sample data
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
passport_country <- lapply(gsub("[()]","",entry), function(x) 
  as.character(wrld_simpl@data$NAME[sapply(wrld_simpl@data$NAME, grepl, x, ignore.case=T)]))
passport_country <- lapply(passport_country, function(x) 
  if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x)
#note that 'Korea, North' is not selected in above comparison as it's offical country name is 'Korea, Democratic People's Republic of'

#final data
df <- data.frame(cbind(passport_no, passport_country))
df
```

Output is:

```
  passport_no passport_country
1   AR4133553               NA
2   472420180               NA
3   563220533               NA
4          NA             Iraq
5          NA               NA
6          NA          Eritrea
7          NA               NA
```

Comment: Above logic for 'Korea, North' can be achieved using


example : 
k = "passport 563220533 (korea, north)"



Output :
regmatches(k, gregexpr("(?<=\\().*(?=\\))", k, perl=T))

finding it difficult to append the same logic in the code above for passport country detetion.

Request you to please help on this

Comment: If the variation in country name is parentheses closure only then you can try - `passport_country_commaSeparated <- lapply(regmatches(entry, gregexpr("(?<=\\().*(?=\\))", entry, perl=T)), function(x) if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x);
df <- data.frame(cbind(passport_no, passport_country=ifelse(!is.na(passport_country), passport_country, passport_country_commaSeparated)));
df`